# How do I set up Alembic for a SQLite database attached as a schema?

Tags: python, database, sqlite, sqlalchemy, alembic

I've tried many contortions on this problem to try to figure out what's going on.

My SQLAlchemy code specified tables as schema.table. I have a special connection object that connects using the specified connect string if the database is PostgreSQL or Oracle, but if the database is SQLite, it connects to a :memory: database, then attaches the SQLite file-based database using the schema name. This allows me to use schema names throughout my SQLAlchemy code without a problem.

But when I try to set up Alembic to see my database, it fails completely. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I included my own answer to this question because I was able to get this working, and the various problems weren't obvious to me. But I'd love to know if anyone has better solutions or additional insights. I'd also like to know if there are parts of either my question or answer that are too obsure to be useful. I'd like to correct those while the answer is still fresh in my mind!

Answer (score 2):

I ran into several issues that had to be worked through before I got this working.

Initially, Alembic didn't see my database at all. If I tried to specify it in the alembic.ini file, it would load the SQLite database using the default schema, but my model code specified a schema, so that didn't work. I had to change `alembic/env.py` in `run_migrations_online()` to call my connection method from my code instead of using `engine_from_config`. In my case, I created a database object that had a `connect()` method that would return the `engine` and the `metadata`. I called that as `connectable, meta = db.connect()`. I would return the schema name with `schema=db.schema()`. I had to import the `db` class from my SQLAlchemy code to get access to these.

Now I was getting a migration that would build up the entire database from scratch, but I couldn't run that migration because my database already had those changes. So apparently Alembic wasn't seeing my database. Alembic also kept telling me that my database was out of date. The problem there was that the alembic table `alembic_version` was being written to my `:memory:` database, and as soon as the connection was dropped, so was the database. So to get Alembic to remember the migration, I needed that table to be created in my database. I added more code to `env.py` to pass the schema to `context.configure` using the `version_table_schema=my_schema`.

When I went to generate the migration again, I still got the migration that would build the database from scratch, so Alembic STILL wasn't seeing my database. After lots more Googling, I found that I needed to pass `include_schemas=True` to `context.configure` in `env.py`. But after I added that, I started getting tracebacks from Alembic.

Fortunately, my configuration was set up to provide both the connection and the metadata. By changing the `target_metadata=target_metadata` line to `target_metadata=meta` (my local metadata returned from the connection), I got around these tracebacks as well, and Alembic started to behave properly.

So to recap, to get Alembic working with a SQLite database attached as a schema name, I had to import the connection script I use for my Flask code. That connection script properly attaches the SQLite database, then reflects the metadata. It returns both the engine and the metadata. I return the engine to the "connectable" variable in env.py, and return the metadata to the new local variable meta. I also return the schema name to the local variable schema.

In the with connectable.connect() as connection: block, I then pass to context.configure additional arguments `target_metadata=meta`, `version_table_schema=schema`, and `include_schemas=True` where meta and schema are my new local variables set above.

With all of these changes, I thought I was able to work with SQLite databases attached as schemas. Unfortunately, I continued to run into problems with this, and eventually decided that I simply wouldn't work with SQLite with Alembic. Our rule now is that Alembic migrations are only for non-SQLite databases, and SQLite data has to be migrated to another database before attempting an Alembic migration of the data.

I'm documenting this so that anyone else facing this may be able to follow what I've done and possibly get Alembic working for SQLite.

Comment: Unfortunately, this answer isn't very good. Changing target_metadata=target_metadata to target_metadata=meta means I'm using the reflected metadata from the database. This is explicitly NOT the metadata I want to be using because it doesn't include the changes to the model I've made. But using metadata=metadata causes a traceback ending with:
modify_ops.ops.append(ops.DropIndexOp.from_index(obj.const))
`File ".../site-packages/alembic/operations/ops.py", line 1030, in from_index`
`index.table.name,`
`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'`